# Animating the UICollectionView Footer height

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I'm currently changing the height of my footer from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

     if shouldDisplay(){
                return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
     }else{
                return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0)
     }
}
```

But this doesn't provide the best user experience. I want to animate the height and provide a smooth (dis)appearance.

Unfortunately, I did not find any resources on this.

Comment: You animate views with UIView.animate()

Comment: Yes, but not uicollectionview components

Comment: Then you should animate the constraints instead.

Comment: Specifically: set the constraint somewhere, then with a `UIView.animate` block, deactivate the old constraint and activate the new constraint.

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this does not work for me :(

Comment: Hi Johanna. As an editor, I often remove chatty material such as greetings, thanks and appreciation from posts here. The canonical discussion for this sort of edit [is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). More recently, I have also floated the theory that some forms of politeness may be [more likely to receive downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions). So, while succinctness is preferred here, it may even be useful in terms of how posts are received.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and implement `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElement`, `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElement` functions.

You can get more information about custom layouts [here](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/practical-introduction-to-custom-uicollectionview-layouts)